# Converting React Class to Functional Components with Hooks. How to fix "uncontrolled input" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have the following code that I understand and it works perfectly.It is a class component. I am trying to write a working function component version with hooks. My refactor is giving me the infamous "uncontrolled input" error. I did not have the error until I used `useEffect`. I want to know how to fix the error. Thank you.

**Old (Working) Class Component**

```
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        clients: [],
        clientName:undefined
      }    

      this.clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients')

    }

    handleChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
        });
        console.log(this.state.clientName);
    }

    addNewClient=(event,userID)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        this.clientsRef.push({
          name: this.state.clientName,
          user_id:userID
        });

        this.setState({
              clientName:""
        })

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
           const client = snapshot.val();
           client.key = snapshot.key;
           this.setState({ clients: [...this.state.clients, client]})
        });

        // this.state.clients.concat(client) 
     }

    /*_______________________________________________


    Add new company and associate it with a specific user ID

    _________________________________________________*/
    //


    render(){
      const {classes} = this.props;


      return(
        <Consumer>
        {(userData)=>{
           if(userData.state.user){
               console.log(userData.state.user);
           }

          return(






             <div className={classes.root}>
                  <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Paper>

                      </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>


                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Paper className={classes.paper}>


                          <div>
                               <h1>Add new client or company</h1>
                               <form onSubmit = {(event)=>this.addNewClient(event,userData.state.userID)}>
                                 <input type="text" name="clientName" onChange = {this.handleChange} value ={this.state.clientName}/>
                                 <input type="submit" value="add client"/>
                               </form>

                                <ul> 

                                 {
                                   this.state.clients.map((val,index)=>{

                                      if(userData.state.userID === val.user_id){
                                        return <a key={index} href={`/dashboard/${userData.state.userID}/company/${val.name}/${val.key}`}> 
                                          <ListItem>{val.name}</ListItem>   
                                        </a>


                                      } 
                                   }) 
                                 }

                                 </ul>
                          </div>



                       </Paper>


                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>


                    </Grid>

                  </Grid>

                  </div>


            )
          }
        }
       </Consumer>

      )
    }
}
```

**Functional Component Version that Gives the Error.**

```
function Dashboard(props){

    const initialState = {
        clients: [],
        clientName:""
      }    

    const [formState,setForm] = useState(initialState);
    const clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');

    function handleChange(evt){
        setForm({...formState,
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
        });

        console.log(formState)

    }


    function addNewClient(event,userID){
        event.preventDefault();
        clientsRef.push({
          name: formState.clientName,
          user_id:userID
        });


        setForm({
            clientName:""
        })

    }



    function fetchData() {
        clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
           const client = snapshot.val();
           console.log(client)
           client.key = snapshot.key;
           setForm({ clients: [...formState.clients, client]})
        });


     }


    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData()
    },[])







    /*_________________*/




      const {classes} = props;
      const userData = useContext(Context);



          return(

             <div className={classes.root}>
                  <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Paper>

                      </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>


                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Paper className={classes.paper}>


                          <div>
                               <h1>Add new client or company</h1>
                             <form onSubmit={(event)=>addNewClient(event,userData.state.userID)} >
                               <input type="text" name="clientName" onChange = {handleChange} value = {formState.clientName}/>
                               <input type="submit" value="add client"/>
                             </form>

                            <ul> 

                              {
                                 formState.clients.map((val,index)=>{

                                    if(userData.state.userID === val.user_id){
                                      return <a key={index} href={`/dashboard/${userData.state.userID}/company/${val.name}/${val.key}`}> <ListItem>{val.name}</ListItem></a>


                                    } 
                                 }) 
                              }

                            </ul>
                          </div>
                       </Paper>

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>

                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
              </div>


            )



}
```

Comment: Does it tell you specifically where error occurs, line number/code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updator, `setForm`, returned from `useState` works differently from `this.setState`.

While `this.setState` in Class Component automatically [merges existing states](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged), the hook's updator (`setForm`) [doesn't automerge existing state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables).

> ... However, unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.

When you set clients in `fetchData`,

```
function fetchData() {
  clientsRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    const client = snapshot.val();
    console.log(client);
    client.key = snapshot.key;

    //  
    setForm({ clients: [...formState.clients, client] });
  });
}
```

`setForm({ clients: [...formState.clients, client] });` turns `clientName` into `undefined`.

You'd need to spread existing state (as you do with reducer or Redux) to return a new reference containing `clientName`, which was set to the value for `input` below.

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="clientName"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={formState.clientName}
/>;
```

When you fetch data, that input field gets `uncontrolled` because `formState.clientName` is undefined.

So return a new reference without clearing `clientName`.

```
setForm(previousForm => ({
  ...previousForm,
  clients: [...formState.clients, client]
}));
```

Comment: Moreover, react advises to use individual setters for each property on state that you are using in the component.

Comment: What @Rikin says is correct. And also If the state gets too big, or have to use such big object that are related, try to use `useReducer` instead.

Comment: @Sung M. Kim ... this works an I should have caught it. I'll check off your answer. I do have another async problem. I am expecting to get back a list of objects in which the values are presented to the user in the DOM. As the code is, only the last item in the list that is retrieved from firebase is displayed. I'll post another query but I thought you might see the prob. Thanks again!